# Apple Pay iOS integration

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, payment, applepay

I'm searching for Moneris ios SDK implementation under below link
https://developer.moneris.com/en/Documentation/NA/Card%20Present%20Solutions/Mobile/iOS

But I couldn't understand how to integrate APPLE PAY I also read below link
https://developer.apple.com/reference/applepayjs
but couldn't understand much

So would anyone please tell me something useful or tutorial of Apple Pay. how to integrate it? I couldn't find any solution yet to implement apple pay in Moneris

Comment: Well, If you just search "integrating Apple pay ios" on google the first link is a tutorial

Comment: Google search results vary very much depending on the user. Zeeshain Shaikh might get completely different hits than you. You better provide the link you have found.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help i found the tutorial about it :)